# fprintf: new line after a certain point

Tags: matlab, printf

See code below.

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID, '{%f, %f},    ', array1(1:end))
fclose(fileID)
```

I'd like the output to be in the format of:

```
{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4},
{5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7}, {8,8},
...
```

However, I am instead getting:

```
{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6}, {7,7}, {8,8}, ...
```

Assume a large dataset.

I know I can add a '\n' in the fprintf field but that will just give me a new line after each pair of values.

How do I insert a new line at a certain point after an 'x' amount of "iterations" (in my case, after every 4th pair of values)?

Comment: You probably would need to go through the array with a for loop. Set a counter and an if, everytime counter reaches x, then reset counter to 0 and print a line break.

Comment: @ReneTrujillo  I hear for loops for matlab should be avoided if possible especially with large datasets. Is there no other way in this case?

Comment: @SteveCho, it used to be this way, but nowadays with the JIT compiler there is absolutely nothing wrong with for-loops.

Comment: @NickyMattsson that is good to know for future reference but i am restricted to MATLAB 2012 unfortunately.

Comment: @SteveCho You are restricted to use a 6yo software package? I feel sorry for you. However, I am still fairly certain that the for-loop is not going to be the limiting factor but rather how fast you can write to the harddisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, you have to create the format for the entire line:

```
nb_pairs = 4;
format = [strjoin(repmat({'{%f, %f},'}, 1, nb_pairs), ' ') '\n'];
% format = '{%f, %f}, {%f, %f}, {%f, %f}, {%f, %f},\n'
fprintf(fileID, format, array1);
```

Comment: unfortunately I am using MATLAB 2012 which does not have the strjoin function so I won't be able to test out your code =/

Is there an alternative you know of?

Comment: @SteveCho => [`strjoin` on File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin).

Answer (score 2):

You can **build the format string at runtime**, using `x` as a parameter:

```
x = 4;
fprintf(fileID, [repmat('{%f, %f}, ',1,x-1) '{%f, %f},\n'], array1(1:end))
```

Example in command window:

```
>> array1 = [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8];
>> fileID = 1; % STDOUT
>> x = 4;
>> fprintf(fileID, [repmat('{%f, %f}, ',1,x-1) '{%f, %f},\n'], array1(1:end))
```

prints

```
{1.000000, 1.000000}, {2.000000, 2.000000}, {3.000000, 3.000000}, {4.000000, 4.000000},
{5.000000, 5.000000}, {6.000000, 6.000000}, {7.000000, 7.000000}, {8.000000, 8.000000},
```

If you need to **remove the final comma**, add

```
fprintf(fileID, '\b\b\n')
```

at the end. So, in the previous example,

```
>> fprintf(fileID, [repmat('{%f, %f}, ',1,x-1) '{%f, %f},\n'], array1(1:end)), fprintf(fileID, '\b\b\n')
```

gives

```
{1.000000, 1.000000}, {2.000000, 2.000000}, {3.000000, 3.000000}, {4.000000, 4.000000},
{5.000000, 5.000000}, {6.000000, 6.000000}, {7.000000, 7.000000}, {8.000000, 8.000000}
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that this is similar to the other answer :-/